# Plasma (X11) No Longer Working on Manjaro

Tags: boot, manjaro, plasma

Plasma (X11) Stopped Working

I have had Manjaro on my Lenovo Yoga 9i laptop since I got it, but I just ran into an issue.

I booted up my laptop, and was met with this screen:

[image]

[image]

Sorry for these being taken on my phone, I can’t really use my laptop.

The image says

> The current theme cannot be loaded due to the errors below, please select another theme

I think this refers to a login page theme.

> file:///usr/share/sddm/themes/Nordic/Main.qml:26:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module “org.kde.plasma.core”: Cannot load library /usr/lib/qt/qml/org/kde/plasma/core/libcorebindingsplugin.so: (libplost-2.0.so.3: cannot open shared o next file: No such file or directory)

I think this is saying that my theme was somehow deleted?

Weirder, when I try to login to my account with Plasma (X11) selected, I get rebooted and put back into the login screen.

I don’t remember installing Enlightenment, but I can apparently use these two (both wayland and not). But I’m not sure how to use these, and can’t get wifi to work.

What can I do to get back Plasma?

Regarding the terminal, I can’t seem to use CTRL ALT F1 to open the terminal, but I do have access to VSCode’s inbuilt terminal in Enlightenment. I can’t seem to connect to the WiFi though.

Comment: First question: is `libplist` installed? What does `pacman -F libplist-2.0.so` return?

Comment: @ajgringo619 The output is `extra/libplist 2.2.0-6` `usr/lib/libplist-2.0.so`

Comment: My version is 2.3.0-1, but I'm running EndeavourOS. I also have a symlink to `libplist-2.0.so.4`, but not `libplist-2.0.so.3`. When did you update last?

Comment: @ajgringo619 I honestly don’t think I have updated for half a year or so.  My laptop isn’t connecting to WiFi (possibly related to this?) so I can’t update now.

Comment: Do you have a file named `/etc/sddm.conf.d/kde_settings.conf`? If so, edit it and change the theme to `breeze`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I was able to change my theme using this method, but this doesn’t let me use Plasma unfortunately. It did remove the red text in the login screen though.